# How / Why does the dummy Apigility REST application wotk without end points?

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework2, zend-studio, laminas-api-tools

The video tutorial "[Apigility Integration in Zend Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9L9wf12t370)" shows an example of Apigility application building in Zend Studio. It's an example for RPC.

Now I created a project based on the "Simple Services" template (`New -> Project... -> Apigility Project -> Simple Services`). A simple Zend Framework 2 RESTful Apigility application was created. But I cannot understand how/why.

Usually in Apigility applications the "controller functionality" is / the end points are implemented in the `Resource` classes, right? But the dummy Zend Studio application does not provide any `Resource` class -- and it works without it. How is it possible / does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apigility [documentation](https://apigility.org/documentation/intro/first-rest-service) (`REST Service Tutorial -> Create a REST Service -> [infobox] Code-Connected vs DB-Connected services`) provides the perfect answer:

> **Code-Connected vs DB-Connected services**
>
> When you create a Code-Connected service, Apigility creates a stub
>   "Resource" class that defines all the various operations available in
>   a REST service. These operations return `405 Method Not Allowed`
>   responses until you fill them in with your own code. The
>   "Code-Connected" aspect means that you will be supplying the code that
>   performs the actual work of your API; Apigility provides the wiring
>   for exposing that code as an API.
>
> DB-Connected services allow you to specify a database adapter and a
>   table; Apigility then creates a "virtual" Resource which delegates
>   operations to an underlying [`Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html)
>   instance. In other words, it is more of a rapid application
>   development (RAD) or prototyping tool.

Comment: have you any tutorial for dummy Code-Connected service ?

Comment: The "Getting Started" tutorial describes building of a connected REST service.